# VLC Vetinari (360 video) .NET SDK

Tags: sdk, vlc, 360-degrees

I'm trying to use a VLC player in my C# application, in order to play and control a 360 video.

I'm trying to use the VLC player to do so, but I can't find a SDK that supports 360 videos.

Does anybody know some SDK or API that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this with the LibVLC SDK.

To make sure you're actually dealing with a 360 video, use

```
bool Is360Video => _media.Tracks[0].Data.Video.Projection == VideoProjection.Equirectangular;
```

To update the viewpoint, use

```
MediaPlayer.UpdateViewpoint(yaw, pitch, roll, fov);
```

More info: https://mfkl.github.io/libvlc/360/xamarin/forms/ux/2019/02/12/Fun-with-crossplatform-gestures-and-360-videos.html

Comment: can I UpdateViewpoint using a gyroscope?